# Unknown whitespace appearing inside <div> without padding or margins

Tags: html, css, image, rendering, whitespace

I'm having an odd issue with whitespace in a design I'm building.

I created a `<div>` to contain voting elements - it holds an upvote button, downvote button, and vote total, each inside their own `<div>` element, and using `<img>` for the buttons.

Source:

```
<div class="votebox">
  <div class="vote"><img src="upvote.png" /></div>
  <div class="votetotal">15</div>
  <div class="vote"><img src="downvote.png" /></div>
</div>
```

In the mini-reset in my CSS, both `<div>` and `<img>` elements are defined to display without margins or padding, and FireBug confirms these specific elements have no margins or padding, but I'm seeing whitespace being added between the bottoms of the `<img>` elements and the bottom of their respective containing ` elements.

I added the following CSS to display a border around each element:

```
.votebox * {
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}
```

and this is how it displayed in Firefox 3.6 (yes, those are StackOverflow vote images.. I'm using them as placeholders for the moment):

[image]
Now, the obvious answer to this problem is to simply set the "vote" class to have an explicit height of the images (and I will do this, possibly even opting for CSS sprites over `<img>`s), but I'm much more interested in learning *why* these elements are displaying in this manner (this is supposed to be a self-teaching project after all).

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

---

Edit: Steve H has pointed out to me that I should be using outline, rather than border, to show the outer edges of elements. I've made that change, and also separated the elements in CSS so they each display as a different colour.

The new outline looks like this:

[image]
As you can see, the issue is a bit different than I thought. It looks like there is some whitespace below the image, but this is compounded by the fact that the bottom image seems to be rendered slightly outside its containing `<div>`. This seems weird to me.

Comment: [Just a tip] When debugging problems like this it is usually better to use outline instead of border, this is because border will add to the overall width/height of an object whereas outline will just mark the outer regions.

Comment: Somehow, I wasn't aware of outline. I knew going into this that the border would increase the width/height of the elements, but considered it a non-issue since I'd already inspected everything with firebug and just wanted to be able to see multiple elements at once, rather than one at a time with firebug. Interestingly, outline and border look different from each other, and there is an outline line that I can't identify (doesn't appear at the edge of any element when inspected with firebug).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Images in HTML are inline elements and are by default placed on the font base line, so what you are seeing is probably the space for the descenders. The usual way around this is either setting them to `display: block` or `vertical-align: bottom`.

EDIT: BTW, you can format images with CSS just like any other element, so you can mostly likely drop the extra `div`s around the images.

Comment: Excellent explanation; just what I was looking for. Both of your methods worked, but `display: block;` threw the image to the left of the container (I know this one though: it's because a block, by default, has 100% width).

Comment: This also applies to other elements that are `inline-block` too. I had a similar issue just now to the OP with a menu `ul` that had been set to Inline Block and had the random whitespace underneath. Adding the `vertical-align: middle;` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the doctype you use. If you use Transitional ( `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` ) it will be shown in the way you want.

example with transitional: http://jsbin.com/icesi

example with strict: http://jsbin.com/icesi/2

A related statement that may help you understand the issue is the following

> Here's another example. You may have
>   found that setting font-size: medium
>   results in different font sizes in
>   Explorer versus Navigator. This occurs
>   because of the way the Internet
>   Explorer for Windows team interpreted
>   the intent of the CSS specification.
>   In order to stay consistent with the
>   Windows version, Internet Explorer for
>   the Macintosh emulated its behavior in
>   the 4.x series. If you put IE5/Mac
>   into bugwards compatibility mode, it
>   will continue to treat font-size:
>   medium as IE4.x/Win does. **In strict
>   mode however, it will act as Navigator
>   does, which is actually the correct
>   interpretation according to the W3C.**

Source: http://oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/synd/2001/08/28/doctype.html?page=2

Comment: I didn't realize the doctype was so important. I had read that the doctype mainly is used to force the browser into standards mode. I can't find it now, but I saw an answer on SO a couple days ago that said or implied that browsers don't actually use the doctype for anything else. I guess that was wrong. For the record, I was using the HTML5 doctype.

Comment: I added a additional comment from an oreilly, check it, maybe will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your using a strict doctype, so

```
.votebox img{display:block;}
```

Should do the trick