# Preventing Site-Navigation Overlapping Header On Mobile Devices

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, background, navigationbar

My website is www.rosstheexplorer.com.

I was recently given the following code -

```
body.custom-background {
  background-image: none;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 800px) 
  {
  .main-navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: none;
  }
}


@media screen and (min-width: 661px) {
  img.header-img {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

On non mobile devices this solved the problem I was having with H1 and the plugins overlapping the navigation menu. Annoyingly on mobile devices the problem persists.

I tried to resolve the problem on mobile devices by modifying the code to the below but it sadly did not give me the desired result. Does anyone have a suggestion?

```
body.custom-background {
  background-image: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1px) 
  {
  .main-navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 661px) {
  img.header-img {
    display: block;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  img.mobile-header-img {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This occures because you mobile navigation menu has **negative** bottom **margin**. Because of that, it just "*pulls*" content from underneath it.

[image: Negative margins]

To fix that you need to reset the bottom margin like so...

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 799px){
    .main-navigation {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```